# how to define the polynomial for CRC algorithm?

Tags: java, checksum, crc

I wrote a code that calculates the CRC24 checksum:

```
public String CRC24Q(String str){
    String devisor = "1100001100100110011111011";
    String augmented = str + appendZeroes("0", 23);
    StringBuilder checksum = new StringBuilder();
    String tmp = augmented.substring(0, 24);
    for (int j = 0; j < devisor.length()-1; j++){
        if (tmp.charAt(j) == devisor.charAt(j)){
            checksum.append('0');
        } else {
            checksum.append('1');
        }
    }
    for (int i = 24; i < augmented.length()-1; i++){
        tmp = checksum.toString().substring(1) + augmented.charAt(i);
        checksum.setLength(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < devisor.length(); j++){
            if (tmp.charAt(j) == devisor.charAt(j)){
                checksum.append('0');
            } else {
                checksum.append('1');
            }
        }
    }
    return checksum.toString();
}
```

however i have a problem with defining the polynomial. 
i have defined it based on the instructions provided in a certain document:
[image]

does my polynomial should be the little p or the g?
thank you for your help.

Comment: Not an expert, but from what I understood of the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_code g is the polynomial, p is only the irreductible form. So g(X) form is all you need, the rest is just an explanation on how they got to this equation.

Comment: g(X) is what you want!

Comment: ok, another thing. i am trying to check if my calculation is correct. so after calculating the check sum i add it to the original string and calculate again with out padding the message again. thew checksum should be 0 but sometimes it is not. is there any problem with my calculation?

Answer (score 0):

It's the g. A 24-bit CRC polynomial has x<sup>24</sup> as the highest power term.